# Function preprocess_views_view if not logged in

Tags: views, theming

I have added two javascripts for one page only using preprosess in template.php. The two scripts seem to work well.

The jquery version I include on this page/view is interfering with admin overlay and other stuff for the editor. I'd like to apply this preprosess only if the user is not logged in.

```
/**
 * Equal height row javascript + jquery 1.10.2 - in page-view (my-view-page)
 */
function mytheme_preprocess_views_view(&$vars) {
   $view = $vars['view'];
   // Make sure it's the correct view
  if($view->name == 'myview') {
     // add needed javascript
     drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'mytheme') . '/js/jquery-v1-10-2.js');
     drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'mytheme') .'/js/equal-height-row.js');
  }
}
```

Is it possible to correct this function to make sure the scripts are not served to logged in users? Or does it require a different approach like preprocess_html?

(For now there is not going to be registered users other than editors)

(Using Drupal 7.25 and custom subtheme of Responsive Bartik)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, add either:

```
global $user;
```

to your function and check its `uid` status or wrap the `drupal_add_js` in an `IF` block using the Core API function [user_is_logged_in()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_is_logged_in/7)

For exmaple:

```
$user_is_not_logged_in = (user_is_logged_in() === FALSE);
if ($user_is_not_logged_in) {
  if ($view->name == 'foo') {
    /* drupal_add_js(...); */
  }
}
```

**EDIT:**

So the full thing (doing your homework for you) would look like this:

```
/**
 * Equal height row javascript + jquery 1.10.2 - in page-view (my-view-page)
 */
function mytheme_preprocess_views_view(&$vars) {
   $view = $vars['view'];
   // Make sure it's the correct view
  if($view->name == 'myview') {
    if (!user_is_logged_in()) {
      // add needed javascript
       drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'mytheme') . '/js/jquery-v1-10-2.js');
       drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'mytheme') .'/js/equal-height-row.js');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I would say the extra variable is probably not needed though, you could just do if (!user_is_logged_in()) { // do stuff. }

Comment: @tenken Sorry for any silly questions - but are this going inside the `function mytheme_preprocess_views_view(&$vars)`?

Comment: see my edit. I wrote out english describing the solution so you might better learn something. by giving you something to copy and paste; you learn less.

Comment: @tenken I appreciate your effort on this. I've already tried this solution based on your first suggestion, and the javascripts does not show for any visitor. My original code works, but serves the javascripts to all visitors.

Comment: Sorry. My testing method where not right. I finally got it working. Thank you for your patience